# How do I save and run a script I've altered in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to learn some basics from an online course here so bear with me please?

I have an example script which i ran and this error;

> the following arguments are required: source_ip, destination_ip

In my unknowing brain it means i need to actually add the ip addresses yes? It's kind of irrelevant really if I'm wrong I'm more interested in how I alter an existing script through Pycharm save it as a different name, then run that that script in my terminal which is gitbash?

So I opened the script in Pycharm and added the ip addresses. How do I save that script as a different name and then run it through pycharm?

Comment: i may have done it, I created a new scratch pad and named it whatever,py and saved that, is that the correct procedure?

Comment: Pycharm saves every file change automatically. There's no manual step to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you select `Run`, `Edit Configurations...` on Pycharm top menu, you will see a screen to define the arguments used when you run your python script:
[image]
In the `Parameters` box you can enter the actual values of the parameters you want to use. I entered names in the example, but you should see the actual parameters values you would pass to the function from the command prompt.
That will pass the configured parameters to your script every time you run it in Pycharm.